# Changing the item text size in navigation view

Tags: android, navigationview

I am creating a navigation drawer in android and I have added the items in menu_main.xml but I am not able to change the size of the menu items.
Below is the code
menu_main.xml:

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/motel"
        android:title="Motel">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/packages"
        android:title="Packages">
    </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by size? Do you mean height or width?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: I meant the textSize.For example the size of the text Motel

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create a style and apply it to NavigationView using `app:theme`

```
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> <!-- menu item text size-->
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
</style>
```

And then as said, apply this style to NavigationView using `app:theme`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       ...
       ...    
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
       ...
       ...


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Thank you paresh.Worked well

Comment: app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle" didn't worked and android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle" worked. Why is that?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani Thnx ! but I want specific one item text size increases or decreases

Answer (score 8):

Adding on to Paresh's answer above,

Create your own style "NavigationViewStyle" as stated above

```
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply it to your menu items

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        .
        .
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        . />
```

Comment: what about when on different screen sizes, is this automatically changed depending on density? I mean on a tablet the textSize is larger right