# Adding font size to NavigationView item in android

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview, android-navigationview, android-selector

In navigationView when i select an item, the selected item should be in bold and increase in font size. How do i achieve this?

Basically, I want to add a selector for the navigation item which will display bold font on selected state and normal font on non-selected state.

Thanks

Comment: try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140138/changing-the-item-text-size-in-navigation-view

Comment: I want to create a selector for the navigation item. I want different text size and styles for selected item and non-selected item

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221637/android-navigation-view-item-menu-background-color

Comment: Through above link we can only change the color of item in different states but I want to change the font size and style of item selected. Is there any way for it?

Comment: Then i think you have to code for it on item click.

Comment: like this https://blog.samsao.co/how-to-customize-the-text-appearance-of-a-selected-section-in-a-navigation-drawer-c6c372e27b66#.c2p91lwph

Comment: @VishalThakkar Yes this is possible when creating own listview and adapters But is it not possbile with NavigationView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below

```
    //put this in main Activity
private void setFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , font), 0 , mNewTitle.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

Use like this

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i=0;i<m.size();i++) {
        MenuItem item = m.getItem(i);

        //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
        SubMenu subMenu = item.getSubMenu();
        if (subMenu!=null && subMenu.size() >0 ) {
            for (int j=0; j <subMenu.size();j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                setFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
            }
        }

        //the method we have create in activity
        setFontToMenuItem(item);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with this and this doesn't work for me. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: style tag is not supported for selector item.So this doen't work

Comment: @Divya have  you try like this??

Comment: @Divya Enjoy coding

Answer (score 4):

Styles.xml

```
    <style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

and then in your NavigationView:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
         />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I want to create a selector for the navigation item. I want different text size and styles for selected item and non-selected item